# Iterating twice over HashMap Java

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, listiterator

I have a HashMap declared as

```
static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> inverted_index = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I iterated over its keys as

```
    public static void printInvertedIndex() throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("InvertedIndex.txt"));
    Iterator it = inverted_index.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        writer.println(pair.getKey() + "  " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove();
        }

    writer.close();
}
```

I did all this in a function called printInvertedIndex().
Now in some other function I want to iterate over the HashMap again, so I did this

```
    public static void createPermutermIndex(){
    permuterm_index.clear();

    Iterator it = inverted_index.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("here");
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String temp;
        temp = pair.getKey() + "$";
        ArrayList<String> perms = rotations(temp);
        System.out.println(perms.size());
        for(int i=0; i<perms.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(perms.get(i));
            //permuterm_index.put(temp, perms.get(i));
        it.remove();
        }
    }
```

But I am not getting "here" printed while calling createPermutermIndex(). That is, my iterator is not iterating over the entries of inverted_index.

Is there any way I can iterate over it again?

Comment: Your `inverted_index` `Map` is clearly empty.

Comment: Why are you using raw type `Iterator`? You clearly know about generics from your `Map` declaration.

Comment: @BoristheSpider from my personal experience, using generics and knowing about them is a very different thing. You get to do the earlier much prior to the latter if you were born and raised on Java 5+.

Comment: @Mena why do you say so? I am getting the output from the function printInvertedIndex()

Comment: @rpn8281 sure, but you're _deleting the entries from the map as you do it_!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    writer.println(pair.getKey() + "  " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // <- This is your problem
}
```

You're *removing* the entries while you're iterating through them. When the loop exits, you will have deleted all the entries in the map. Therefore, it's not surprising that the second loop doesn't do anything - there is nothing left to iterate over.

It doesn't seem like you want to remove anything during these loops, so just remove those `it.remove()` lines in your two loops.

Comment: Good catch. Also, is it a convention to iterate over an `Iterator` object rather than directly using `HashMap.entrySet()`?

Comment: @nyxaria That's quite normal, although these days it might be preferable to use `for (Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> pair : invertedIndex.entrySet()) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Comment: @rpn8281 if the answer answered your question, consider accepting it.